# Read notifications from other iOS apps?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Is there something like the notificationlistenerservice in Android in iOS, where you can monitor for other apps' notifications?

Comment: No. Apps can only deal with their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and I wouldn’t hold my breath for such an API to appear. There’d be serious privacy and security issues to address for very limited benefit.

Comment: Hmm, seems kind of weird when you consider that Apple already provides such a service(ANCS) for other devices. Thanks!